# how get user id from specific voice channel for move in another channel

Tags: move, discord.js, channel, voice

I make a bot for creating voice channel, not with a command but with to join to specific voice channel.

Actually i'm stuck for move my user into the new voice channel, some one can help me ?

```
if (idVoiceChannel === "607195759314910090") { 
        newMember.guild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'voice' }).then(nM => { nM.setParent(category.id); nM.edit({userLimit: 4}); });
        console.log(newUserChannel)
        //when channel is created move the user into this
    } else if(idVoiceChannel === "607245896250755073") {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method for moving a member to channel.
In your case:

```
newMember.setVoiceChannel(nM)
```

It looks cleaner if you make your function async,

```
if (idVoiceChannel === "607195759314910090") { 
        const nM = await newMember.guild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'voice' })
        nM.setParent(category.id)
        nM.edit({userLimit: 4})
        newMember.setVoiceChannel(nM)
    } else if(idVoiceChannel === "607245896250755073") {

    }
```

Comment: make your parent function `async`,
`function async [name] { ... }` instead of `function [name] { ... } `

Comment: i try lot of time include async into my function but i can no do it. this is my full file (sry for this) https://pastebin.com/g3KVKaNG

Comment: `bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember)`

Comment: Make sure to catch rejected promises.